# Footer is transparent and dont know why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So my footer is transparent on every page. I don't know why it is but it is.

I would like to keep it transparent on the home page, but have a white bg on every other page. Any suggestions on the best way to go about this would be awesome. I have tried using many different bootstrap methods, but it always changes the bg on the home page as well, and pushes the footer to the top of the page??

I'm using rails 4.2.

_footer.html.erb

```
<body class="footer">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">  
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">  
                <li><%= link_to "Privacy", privacy_path  %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Terms", terms_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
                </ul>
          </form>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</body>
```

styles.css.scss (haven't input anything for the footer)

```
$navbar-default-bg: white;
$btn-default-bg: white;


@import 'bootstrap';


body {          
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 50px;           
    }


.searchbox > div {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width:600px;
}

.hb{

a {
    color:white;
    }
.privacycolor{
        color:white;
    }
.termscolor{
        color:white;
    }
.aboutcolor{
        color:white;
    }
.logincolor {
    color:white;
}
.signupcolor {
    color:white;
}
.navbar-brand{
    color:white;
}       
    color:white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: asset-data-url("boom1.jpg")        
}
.innercover{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ab {  
    .featurette-heading {
        margin-top: 150px;
        }
}
.progress{
    height: 24px;
}

.mcds {
    .well {
    background-color: white;
    }
    .jumbotron {
    color:white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: asset-data-url("doi.jpg") 
    }
    .row {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title> Check it out </title>
                <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
                <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
                <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

        </head>
    <body>

                <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
            <div class="container">
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
                <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you need any other pages please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: Change `<body class="footer">` to  `<div class="footer">` and `</body>` to `</div>` in _footer.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for the help! How can I change the background color to white? I tried navbar-default-bg: white; but doesn't change anything.

Comment: try `.footer { backgroud-color: $navbar-default-bg; }` in styles.css.scss

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you probably want to add a class to the body tag on your main page: <body class="home">.  Then try: body .footer {background=color: transparent}   body.home .footer{ background-color: #fff}